# ClickOnce change WS URL dynamically

Tags: c#, url, clickonce, environment

I develop the ClickOnce application (C# Framework 4.5)
It access data through Web Service. 
We have three environments: dev, test and prod.
Each environment - another server name. 
I would like to make one publish and copy it to each environment with external tool.
Problem, to access correct url for web service for each environment.
I need to change url dynamically in code for each environment.

I add to app.config the WS references

```
<add key="ws_url_local" value="http://localhost/app/ws.asmx" />
<add key="ws_url_prod" value="http://server_prod/app/ws.asmx" />
<add key="ws_url_test" value="http://server_test/app/ws.asmx" />
<add key="ws_url_dvlp" value="http://server_dvlp/app/ws.asmx" />
```

I make a publish into folder, and then, another system copy the folder to
all environments. 
How I can change dynamically the url by environment in code?

```
switch(fromWhereInstaled?){
  case "prod":
    url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ws_url_prod"];
    break;
  case "test":
    ...
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Found solution:

```
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url_ws_local"];
if(ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
  ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
  if(ad.ActivationUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("prodservername"))
  {
    url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url_ws_prod"];
  }
  else if ad.ActivationUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("testservername")
  .....
}
ws.Url = url;
```

But if you move your application without update ActivationUri, use this solution:

```
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url_ws_local"];
if(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArgument != null && AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArgument.ActivationData != null) // Network published
{
  string strParam = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArgument.ActivationData[0];
  if(strParam.Contains("prodservername"))
  {
    url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url_ws_prod"];
  }
  else if ...
}
ws.Url = url;
```

But don't forget go to Properties=>Publish>Options=>Manifests, and check:
Allow URL parameters to be passed to application.
Also in this way you can change url for check updates.